Office add-in clear the snapshot
i develop a content add-in for powerpoint and it works fine. 
the add-in is a web browser which only contains iframe, textbox and button. 
i save the ppt and share whom have not installed the add-in in his client. 
when he open the ppt, the add-in shows the snapshot of last web page and a yellow warning of installation for add-in. 
is there any settings or Javascript APIs to clear the snapshot?

No way to clear.
Workaround:
Blank Page as Default: Set the src of the iframe to a blank page or some neutral placeholder when the add-in isn’t active. This way, the snapshot will show a blank or neutral image instead of the last web page.
Dynamic Loading: Use JavaScript to dynamically load the actual content into the iframe only when the add-in is active. This helps make sure the snapshot stays blank or neutral when the add-in isn’t installed.
